Why my .bat file stop after build an image
i have build my app and write a build.bat file for automate build and push my image to docker hub
my build.bat file
@echo off
echo Building Image Config-server

cd ./backend/services/config-server
mvn compile com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:3.4.4:build -Dimage=niesuv/config-server
cd ../../../

echo --------------------------------------
echo Building Image Gateway-service
cd ./backend/services/gateway-service
mvn compile com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:3.4.4:build -Dimage=niesuv/gateway-service
cd ../../../

echo --------------------------------------
echo Building Image Post-service
cd ./backend/services/post-service
mvn compile com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:3.4.4:build -Dimage=niesuv/post-service
cd ../../../

echo --------------------------------------
echo Building Image S3-service
cd ./backend/services/s3-service
mvn compile com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:3.4.4:build -Dimage=niesuv/s3-service
cd ../../../


echo --------------------------------------
echo Building Image User-service
cd ./backend/services/user-service
mvn compile com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:3.4.4:build -Dimage=niesuv/user-service

it runs and push the first image(config-server) perfectly but stop after that, here is the log
Building Image Config-server
...
...
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  24.780 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-11-01T22:50:31+07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------


can s.o help me fix that bug. is there any way better to build it automate rather than this way.
here is my project structure
Project_name
_backend
_service
_configserver(springboot pj)
_gateway-service(springboot pj)
_user-service(springboot pj)
sorry for my bad english and bad description
i have run the command line by line in cmd console and run perfectly

All of your cd commands are using Unix format instead of Windows, e.g. ./backend/services/config-server should be backend\services\config-server and cd ../../../ should be ..\..\... Also you'd be far better off in this case using pushd and popd. For example, your lines 4, 5, & 6: PushD "backend\services\config-server", Call "%ProgramFiles%\Maven\apache-maven-3.9.9\bin\mvn.cmd" compile com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:3.4.4:build -Dimage=niesuv/config-server, PopD.

You need to add call if you want to return from the mvn.bat file. See: How to execute more than one maven command in bat file?
